# Стандартный итератор со своими "плюшками" - PHP

Tags: php

Очень часто при переборе разных массивов данных через foreach, нужно в самом цикле проверить является ли текущий элемент первым, или предпоследним и другие подобные задачи?

Чтобы каждый раз не заводить переменную перед циклом, и не делать нужные проверки инкрементируя перменную, какие могут быть решения с интераторами?

Т.е. могу ли наследовать класс Iterator и в нем дописать свои методы isFirst() и т.д.? 
Можно пожалуйста пример?

Или как по другому можно правильным способом решить эту задачу?

```
$i = 0;
$len = count($array);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        // first
    } else if ($i == $len - 1) {
        // last
    }
    // …
    $i++;
}
```

Хочется что бы были какие-то методы, что бы постоянно так не делать?

Comment: нафига изобретать велосипед
array_search($key, array_keys($array)); // позиция текущего ключа

Comment: А если массив из тысячи элементов? 
На каждой итерации делать array_search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Достаточно взять [готовый пример из документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.iterator.php) и добавить в класс нужный вам метод. Ниже добавил `isFirst`. По аналогии можете добавить любые другие.

```
class myIterator implements Iterator
{
    private $pos = 0;
    private $ar = [];
    public function __construct(array $ar){
        $this->pos = 0;
        $this->ar = $ar;
    }
    public function rewind(){$this->pos = 0;}
    public function current(){return $this->ar[$this->pos];}
    public function key(){return $this->pos;}
    public function next(){++$this->pos;}
    public function valid(){return isset($this->ar[$this->pos]);}

    public function isFirst(){return $this->pos === 0;}
}

$ar = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
$it = new myIterator($ar);

foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    echo "#{$key}: {$value} (isFirst: ".($it->isFirst() ? "true" : "false").")\n";
}

/* #0: foo (isFirst: true)
   #1: bar (isFirst: false)
   #2: baz (isFirst: false) */
```

Comment: от души!  спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то есть же стандартный подход array_shift (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php) и array_pop (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-pop.php)

Answer (score 0):

у `foreach` есть еще один параметр итерации

```
$first = 0;
$last = count($array)-1;
foreach($array as $index => $item){
  if($first == $index){
    //первый элемент
  }
  if($last == $index){
    //последний элемент
  }
}
```

если я вас правильно понял по поводу классов

```
class IteratorInArray {
    private $array;

    public function __construct($array){
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function isFirst($index){
        return ($index == 0)? true: false;
    }

    public function isLast($index){
        return ($index == (count($this->array) - 1))? true: false;
    }
}

$iterator = new IteratorInArray($arr);
foreach ($arr as $index => $item){
    if($iterator->isFirst($index)){
        var_dump("first");
    }
    if($iterator->isLast($index)){
        var_dump("last");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант, отлов первого элемента мне прямо очень такой нравиться, последнего не очень.

```
$array=range(1,10);

foreach( $array as $v ) {
    if (!$i++) echo ' первый элемент ';
    if ($i==count($array)) echo ' последний элемент ';
    echo $v.'<br>';
}
```